# With BreezeJs, How best to create a new child element for saving?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I know how to pull back an entity, can I can make changes to and say it's a "Company" with "People" in a child node. I can edit those people and save it and it all works great.

However, what I'm not 100% sure is how best to "create" new child object or entity with in that child collection and save it with the parent.

Adding Some Code as requested.

Html Code

```
<div data-ng-controller="updateTerritory as vm">
    Company Name: {{vm.company.name}} : Territory: {{vm.company.territory.name || 'New Territory'}}<br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.company.name"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.company.territory.name" />
    <button data-ng-click="vm.save()">Save Territory</button>
</div>
```

> Route Url: #/company/territory/71/new

Angular Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$location', '$routeParams', 'common', 'datacontext', 'helper', updateTerritory]);

function updateTerritory($location, $routeParams, common, dc, helper) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.company = undefined;

    activate();

    function activate() {
        common.activateController([getRequestedCompany()], controllerId);
    }

    function getRequestedCompany() {
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        var tId = $routeParams.tId;
        //if (tId === 'new') {
            //vm.company.territory = dc.company.territory.create();
            //return vm.company;
        //}

        return dc.company.getById(id)
        .then(function (data) {
            vm.company = data;
        }, function (error) {
            logError("Unable to get company " + id);
        });
    }

    function save() {
        return dc.save()
            .then(function (saveResult) {
            }, function (error) {
                vm.isSaving = false;
            });
    }

}
```

DataContext Service (dc). this works fine for everything so far, even child collections

```
function save() {
        return manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(result) {
            logSuccess("Saved Data", result, true);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

It save's it to the Entity but not to the db, though if I update any properties like Company.Name that saves to the DB. If I try and update say Company.Territory.Name, which doesn't exist and has it's down table in the DB, it doesn't update.

So recap, I can edit and save root properties and child collections, but I'm not sure how to create new entity on the child collection.

Comment: I could help you if I understood what you were asking probably.  Could you show some code?

Comment: Ok added some more context around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Breeze Docs](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/creating-entities)

`var newCust = manager.createEntity('Customer', {name:'Acme'});`

Just do that to create the 'child' object, and then add the new object to the relevant collection on the parent object.

Comment: Ok this works and saves to the DB. Is there a way to get the database ID to store back into the parent? In the example I created the "customer", it stores in the DB but I want to put that customer ID back into the parent which is still null.

Comment: Ahh fixed it had a typo in my edmx, the plural version. Working great now. thanks.